# Magento admin panel shows as html links with executable functions

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, backend

I ran into problems while testing Amazon Payments button on my site and got into rewrite error. I restored my site from a backup database, but the admin panel is missing; only html links are showing up but the links are not executable. My config_data_file are ok where urls are concern and js and css files are not merged.

How do I restore the admin panel for use? Appreciate all advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CSS files are not loading. View the page source and click on a few of the links to CSS files. If you get a 404, then your CSS files are not loading. If you were previously merging your CSS files, change the merge setting to No for now. The same may be true of your JavaScript files.

You can change both of these settings directly in the core_config_data table if necessary. Just search `WHERE path LIKE %merge%` and you should recognize the values that you will need to change.

Comment: Thanks. I checked my config data table but the merge setting for CSS and JS was already "0". I sought professional to troubleshoot the issue and it was resolved in minutes. My problem was not knowing where else to check other than config data table.